# Pandas Group by Values and Merge Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and I want to merge the rows that contain same values

```
toy = [
    [10, 11],
    [21, 22],
    [11, 15],
    [22, 23],
    [15, 33]
]

toy = pd.DataFrame(toy, columns = ['ID1', 'ID2'])
```

```
    ID1 ID2
0   10  11
1   21  22
2   11  15
3   22  23
4   15  33
```

What I am hoping to get afterwards is

```
    0   1   2   3
0   10  11  15  33.0
1   21  22  23  NaN
```

So merging rows that contain any same value within.

My solution is super **NOT** elegant, I am seeking for the right way to do this... Recursion? Groupby? Hmm..

```
#### Feel Free to NOT read this... ###
for k in range(100):
    print(k)

    merge_df = []
    merged_indices = []
    for i, row in toy.iterrows():
        if i in merged_indices:
            continue
        cp = toy.copy()
        merge_rows = cp[cp.isin(row.values)].dropna(how="all")
        merged_indices = merged_indices + list(merge_rows.index)
        merge_rows = np.array(toy.iloc[merge_rows.index]).flatten()
        merge_rows = np.unique(merge_rows)
        merge_df.append(merge_rows)

    if toy.shape[0] == len(merge_df):
        break
    toy = pd.DataFrame(merge_df).copy()
```

Comment: BTW nice pic of  invoker :-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben haha - thx, I like your Saitama too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a network problems so I using `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx 
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(toy, 'ID1', 'ID2')
l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
newdf=pd.DataFrame(l)
newdf
Out[896]: 
    0   1   2     3
0  33  10  11  15.0
1  21  22  23   NaN
```